# Importing ARCharts framework/project into Swift project

Tags: ios, swift, import, frameworks, dependencies

I have tried a myriad of ways to import the following Github project into my Swift iOS project so I can build upon ARCharts, but it did not work. I need to import it manually so I can adapt the graphs design afterwards.

- My Project: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/r0hwil6w5n4a1ie/AAC-O9nDX_6W3kK1nPwWjA3ca?dl=0
- Project to be imported: ARCharts: (https://github.com/Boris-Em/ARCharts)
- I tried dragging the folder "ARCharts" and the following files into my project(Utilities, Settings, SettingsTableViewController and copied all necessary code into my ViewController).
- I received the following Error: ARCharts module not found.
- I then tried to copy the ARCharts.framework file from the sample project which can be found in a temp debug folder. This resolved the issue, but created a new one. Now i am getting many errors in the Extension file all seemingly relating to the fact that Core Animation was not found and therefore could not be extended. (Use of undeclared type 'CABasicAnimation', 'CA...', etc)

The sample project works like a charm, it does not import Core Animation anywhere I can see and somehow seems to generate the framework when compiling. I have tried many ways to resolve the problem by adding the framework from the sample project as embedded framework, linked binaries, target dependencies, etc... But I seem to be missing something. Also the framework file's location does not seem right.

Comment: Looks like this project supports CocoaPods. Is there any reason you don't want to use that?

Comment: If I manage to get Cocoapods working, can I then change the appearance of the graph and the code of the ARCharts project? Thank you!

Comment: If the framework supports customization of the graph's appearance, you can do this using CocoaPods, but you will not be able to modify the source code using CocoaPods.

Comment: Ok I will try to use cocoapods, but it limits me in major ways. It would be infinitely better if I could change the source code.

Answer (score 0):

The author messaged me with what ended up being the solution.
I replaced all the `import ARChart` commands with `import UIKit` and somehow this resolved the problem!

Thank you all

Best Regards,

Samuel Cohen